# Howto recreate a symbol created by `make-symbol`

Tags: common-lisp

My program creates dummy data.  Part of these dummy data are keys in the form of symbols: `(lambda (i) (`[`make-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_sym.htm)`(format nil`[`"~@r"`](https://www.hexstreamsoft.com/articles/common-lisp-format-reference/format-directives/#~R_radix)`i)))` (fixnum values with their Roman numeral as symbol as key).  The program stores these dummy key value pairs in a data structure i'm developing.

I tried to use these symbols from the REPL to test retrieving the values by their key.  However:

```
(equal (make-symbol "IX") (make-symbol "IX"))
```

> NIL

```
(equal (make-symbol "IX") 'IX))
```

> NIL

Is there a way to enter a symbol previously created with [`make-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_sym.htm) in the REPL so that both are `equal`?

Comment: I can solve the problem in testing by using an other type (e.g. string) and not a symbol as key.  Still I wonder how to refer to a symbol generated by `make-symbol` and friends.

Comment: Isn't what `intern` is supposed to do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359304/uninterned-symbols-in-common-lisp about uninterned symbol (such as those created by `make-symbol`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @coredump suggests, use intern to add these symbols into some package, like that:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :my-symbols)
#<Package "MY-SYMBOLS">
CL-USER> (intern "IX" :my-symbols)
MY-SYMBOLS::IX
NIL
CL-USER> (intern "IX" :my-symbols)
MY-SYMBOLS::IX
:INTERNAL
CL-USER> (eql (intern "IX" :my-symbols)
              (intern "IX" :my-symbols))
T
CL-USER>
```

Answer (score 4):

One can use `string=` to compare symbols by name:

```
CL-USER 29 > (string= (make-symbol "IX") (make-symbol "IX"))
T

CL-USER 30 > (string= (make-symbol "IX") (make-symbol "Ix"))
NIL
```

`string-equal` is the case insensitive variant.